# How do I change the value in a loop?

Tags: ruby, calculator

Simple calculation for other variables code. How do I change the value of `closing` if it goes below `0`? What conditions can I use to change its value to `0`? Please give me some examples. The value of `closing` still doesn't change even with other conditions. No matter what conditions I give, it just runs through the loop without changing the value and prints the negative value itself. Is there an issue with my code, or is it the conditioning that I have used in it?

```
unless closing == 0 then
  term_of_loan.to_i.times do |term_of_loan|
    closing = opening - principal
    closing = closing.round(2)
    if closing < 0 then
      closing = 0
      if sum_interest > total_interest then
        print "\t #{months}| \t #{opening}| \t #{interest}| \t #{sum_interest}| \t #{principal}| \t #{closing} \n"
      else
        print "\t #{months}| \t #{opening}| \t #{interest}| \t #{total_interest}| \t #{principal}| \t #{closing} \n"
      end
    else
      if sum_interest > total_interest then
        print "\t #{months}| \t #{opening}| \t #{interest}| \t #{sum_interest}| \t #{principal}| \t #{closing} \n"
      else
        print "\t #{months}| \t #{opening}| \t #{interest}| \t #{total_interest}| \t #{principal}| \t #{closing} \n"
      end
    end
    opening = closing
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you please format/indent your code properly? It's very hard to understand the structure.

Comment: 1. I don't see why outstanding principal should go negative, but if it does you should let it do so. It doesn't make sense to arbitrarily change it to  change zero, for example. 2. To set a variable to zero if it's negative, you can write `x = 0 if x < 0` or `x = [x,0].max`.

Comment: You could use `unless closing <= 0 then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to break the loop as soon as `closing` becomes negative.

To do so, you might either swap condition and loop:

```
term_of_loan.to_i.times do |term_of_loan|
  unless closing == 0 then
    ...
```

or explicitly `break` the loop on negative:

```
if closing < 0 then
  closing = 0
  .....
  break # this is it
```

In your current code, the value of `closing` is set to `zero`, but after it is, the next loop iteration is being entered and `closing = opening - principal` (closing is changed to negative.)

Hope it helps.